# Reconstruct Stanford CoreNLP sentence

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Working with *CoreNLP* I'm trying to make some changes to annotated document.

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
 pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

 Annotation document = new Annotation(input);
 pipeline.annotate(document);

 //TODO (1) change parsed input
 //TODO (2) String reconstructedSentence = ...
```

I'm wondering if there is any standard way to update parsed tree and reconstruct new sentence from this tree?

Comment: To make this a better question and improve your chances of getting good answers, you should add some relevant code and a more detailed description of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I end up with simple solution. Will see how robust is it.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(CoreLabel label : document.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
    if(builder.length() != 0 && needSpaceBefore(label)) {
        builder.append(" ");
    }
    builder.append(processLabel(label));
}
return builder.toString();
```